# Master and Detail must be set before adding MasterDetailPage to a container error in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin forms application. The layout is created by using custom rootpage.cs file. it has the navigation menu for navigating the pages. In the App.cs file redirect to root page by

`MainPage = new RootPage();`

Inside the rootPage class file

```
Dictionary<MenuType, NavigationPage> Pages { get; set; }
    public RootPage()
    {
        Pages = new Dictionary<MenuType, NavigationPage>();
        Master = new MenuPage(this);
        BindingContext = new BaseViewModel
        {
            Title = "Manager",
            Icon = "icon.png"
        };
        NavigateAsync(MenuType.Home);
        InvalidateMeasure();
    }
    public async Task NavigateAsync(MenuType id)
    {
        Page newPage;
        if (!Pages.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            switch (id)
            {
                case MenuType.Home:
                    Pages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new HomePage()));
                    break;
                case MenuType.AboutUs:
                    Pages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new ContactUsPage()));
                    break;
            }
        }
        newPage = Pages[id];
        if (newPage == null)
            return;
        Detail = newPage;
        IsPresented = false;
    }
```

In the  menu page class file have the below code

```
RootPage root;
    public MenuPage(RootPage _root)
    {
        root = _root;
        InitializeComponent();
        List<HomeMenuItemModel> menuItems;
        BindingContext = new BaseViewModel
        {
            Title = "Sample App",
            Subtitle = "Sample App",
            Icon = "icon.png"
        };
        ListViewMenu.ItemsSource = menuItems = new List<HomeMenuItemModel>
            {
              new HomeMenuItemModel { Title = "Home", MenuType = MenuType.Home, Icon ="icon.png" },
              new HomeMenuItemModel { Title = "Contact Us", MenuType = MenuType.ContactUs, Icon ="icon.png" },
              new HomeMenuItemModel { Title = "About Us", MenuType = MenuType.AboutUs, Icon ="icon.png" },
            };
        ListViewMenu.SelectedItem = menuItems[0];
        ListViewMenu.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (ListViewMenu.SelectedItem == null)
                return;
            if (e.SelectedItem != null)
                await this.root.NavigateAsync(((HomeMenuItemModel)e.SelectedItem).MenuType);
            ListViewMenu.SelectedItem = null;
        };
    }
```

HomePage.xaml is just a content page.
While the first run of the application it shows an error "Master and Detail must be set before adding MasterDetailPage to a container error" 
I am new to xamarin. Could you please suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

The error is literally what is going on. You need to set both the `Master` and `Detail` properties of a `MasterDetailPage` before adding it to a containerpage, like for instance, a NavigationPage.

Comment: The Detail property was not set in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add ,n your constructor this code:

```
Master = new MenuPage(this);
Detail = new MenuPage(this);
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs mostly when property Title is missing in XAML.
Check whether you have assigned `Title={Binding Title`} in XAML for sidemenu page and Home page. Please post Log file if this is not fixed.